# Connect to Office not working Sharepoint 2013 and Windows 7

Tags: my-site, office-integration, internet-explorer, windows-7

I cannot for the life of me get the Connect to Office to create any sites within my Sharepoint sites directory on my local computer.  It does create the link in the "My Sites" Quick Links, but i don't see anything within office or the Sharepoint Sites folder.

I am currently running Windows 7 and we are running Sharepoint 2013 On-Premises.
Here are some of the things i have tried.
- Restarting the WebClient
- Setting IE to the default browser
- Removing the c:\Users\Username\Sharepoint Sites folder and Links in My Sites and tried again with no luck.
- Adding the AuthForwardServerList registry entry and set it's value to my intranet domain.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever get an answer? I am running into the same issues and have configured my PC the same way as you describe. Any help is appreciated.